# Applying a local group policy to another user with different username and computer name

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy

A while ago, I setup a dedicated Windows 7 Pro workstation with local group policy applied to a specific guest account. After completion, I made a backup of the applied local group policy setting at `%SystemRoot%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers` directory.

I am now tasked with creating a similar setup and I am wondering if I can apply the same policy to the target computer if I have different username and computer name on the target machine?

The folder name of the backed up local group policy folder is the SID of the user which the policy applied to. Will it work if I copy those files over to the target computer, omit the folder name to reflect the SID of the new user and do a `gpupdate /force`?

Comment: Done this recently from a Domain.Local GPO to another domain and it worked ok so I can't see why local machine to local machine with changing the SID would be a problem. Has to be same OS and if any ADMX are involved make sure they are present on new machine.